# Changing default Battle.net store region

Tags: battle.net

I already have a Battle.net account with European *SCII* on it. I want to pre-purchase *Diablo III*—it's €59,99 in our region, but $59.99 in the US region (cheaper). You can play in any region no matter where you bought the game, so I want to buy the US version.

When I try to get into the US Battle.net store, it tells me that I can only buy from my default region.

Is there a way to change my default region? (I have a close friend in New Zealand that can buy it from NZ, which should be in the American region.)

Comment: I was going to buy in dollar, but in my currency was cheaper. I understand the felling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to change your "COUNTRY OF RESIDENCE" option on battle.net unfortunately it can only be done if you **contact blizzard support** and make up some good story why you need it to be changed.Note that doing this could cause you bunch of new problems.

Other thing you could do is order retail copy online from **Amazon** or any other sites if you manage to find it cheaper,most of the sites have a pre-order discount if you order before game release so you could pass even cheaper,the problem here is you will have to make sure that shipping & border control won't charge you sin you could end up paying even more.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned! If you change your country while participating in a restricted alpha or beta test, you will lose your progress in the original region until Global Play is enabled for the game. You may also lose access to the game entirely if we are not testing in your new region.

Source: https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/battlenet-country-change