# How can I change regions?

Tags: diablo-iii

Where in the interface is the option to switch regions in Diablo 3?

As I understand it, [you have to start with fresh characters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/64356/14). Does this mean you *log in* to a region or can you switch while in-game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change region before logging in. Look into Account tab, inside Options menu.

[image: Account Options]

As you said if you want to change region (this feature is available when all region has launched the game) you have to start a fresh character and you cannot do it "on-the-fly", but you have to exit and re-login.