# Can I share my Diablo 3 account?

Tags: diablo-iii

My brother bought a Diablo 3 copy from China, and i stay in Malaysia. We were thinking whether we can share the same account and play in different country?

Comment: Sharing a Battle.net account is against ToS and can/will result in a Ban from Battle.net for that account (and all games linked to it). It is always a safer option to purchase your own copy of the game.

Comment: Actions that are against ToS are also considered off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 5):

China and Malaysia are both part of the Asian region for purposes of Diablo III. While [Global Play](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5203654) does [allow you to play in any region](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66523/can-i-play-on-whatever-server-i-want), so, for example, if you wanted to play on American servers while your brother played on Asian servers in order to keep characters segregated, you could *technically* do that, there's a bigger problem here.

Specifically, that Blizzards [terms of use](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-account-access-policy) for Diablo III and Battle.net accounts in general explicitly prohibit this sort of behavior. Furthermore, because you're both based in Asia, and using IP addresses in different countries, this is going to expose your account to a *very high* level of scrutiny, meaning it's very probable that you'd be caught, have your account banned, and your license to the game *revoked*.

In short, **I would not suggest doing this. You will probably get banned. It will almost certainly end in tears.**

Comment: That is acctually an interesting thought, and the result of this would most certainly end in despair. If someone doesn't want to spring to pay for two then they'll die paying twice for one.

Comment: @Emerica. At which point buying the second copy would have been better because they spent the same amount, but would actually have access for two accounts.

Comment: @Adanion Its a cruel world.

Answer (score -1):

Your diablo account is not restricted to your region. You can make a character on any region. Of course you will never be able to play together, but there is no reason why region would stop you.

Comment: which means i can use my brother account to login, just we cant login at the same time only right ? but will it crash the diablo3 license agreement

Comment: @KIT As LessPop said, because of the major difference in IP Address the account would most likely be reviewed by Blizzard. And, if you read through the agreements that most people just click okay for, it basically says they can ban you for breaking any of their rules.

Comment: @Emerica - You are not allowed to share a Battle.net account with family members.

Comment: @Ramhound That in no way makes my answer wrong...the account is not restricted by region and that is clear as day. "There is no reason why REGION would stop you". I never said anything about other rules.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you could share it. 
You can decide to play with the same 8 characters or, changing the server, playing with different characters. 
You can choose to play in US ,Euro or ASIA server and for every one you can have 8 characters. 
To change server on main login screen click "Options" then go to "Account" and click "Server Region Selection"

You can't play together but with the same account yes ^^

Comment: sound good ...but will i be the unlucky one and get ban from battle.net? xD

Comment: @KIT - Your account WILL be banned if you share your account with your brother.

Comment: @Shyghar - The limit is 10 character per region.  He is NOT allowed to share the account.