# Can you play with friends in different regions?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buying Diablo 3 in a different region](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/buying-diablo-3-in-a-different-region)

I have seen this post about if [I can change regions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/how-can-i-change-regions), but it doesn't seem to answer my question: **Can you play with someone in a different region?**

**Example:** I am in the North American Region, can I play with a friend or send an invite to someone in the EU Region? Or do I have to create a character in their region (or vice versa)?

(I would presume you cannot as per the same reasons why you cannot change regions *on-the-fly*: such as impacting the AH communities by trading between different region characters - etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play with a person in another region you will first have to create a character on that region.