# How to change your region in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I bought the game in Indonesia and I want to play in American server. How can I do so?

Can I move characters from one region to the other?

In fact I do not know what region I am currently in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change regions?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/how-can-i-change-regions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Options**, **Account**, and select your region in the **Server Region Selection** list in the Game Account column.

Characters are not shared across regions unfortunately though, and there are no known plans to introduce this at the current time AFAIK. Sadly, that means your current heroes are tied to whatever server you are currently playing on.