# Canadian purchased Diablo 3 game back to Europe

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/how-can-i-change-regions)

I currently live in Canada but I am moving back to Europe in about half a year. Can I take my Canadian purchased Diablo 3 game back to Europe and play it there without any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can play. Please look at [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66144/how-can-i-change-regions) for further instructions.

And no, not without problems. If you expect your characters to be available on your "european" account then you are out of luck.

You can try to play on the american servers with your original characters, but only with a huge delay. Well, you can try it yourself.

Official post:

> I'm sorry but we cannot transfer characters between regions, and we do not have plans  to implement such a feature at this time.

[Source](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4077738830?page=3)

Comment: You can try to play Diablo from Canada on the European servers. It will have a similar delay to playing from Europe on American servers. Perhaps you can live with the lag.