# Can I purchase a copy of Diablo III from the US Blizzard Store to play on EU server?

Tags: diablo-iii

Because of the ridiculous price difference Between the US and EU Blizzard Stores ($60 vs, 60€(~$76), ~27% more), I was considering purchasing Diablo 3 on a US Battle.net account and (as a gift) send the authentication key to my EU account, which I primarily use.

- Would this work? If so, would I be able to play with my EU server friends?
- Does Blizzard have any rule against doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there may be consequences in terms of your ability to use the real-money auction house, since you only have access to the real-money auction house for one region. Whether or not that would be a significant disadvantage depends partly on whether you'd spend real money on items (or try to cash out real money from the game), and on whether the good stuff ends up being equally available in both auction houses, which remains to be seen.

Comment: So ... what did you end up doing? BTW, if I have a dollar paypal account, then I suppose a US account will be at least as good for purpose of selling off items in exchange for real money.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/buying-diablo-3-in-a-different-region

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can play with your friends in Europe from a US account. Just change your server selection settings in options to Europe

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do what you want to do. At least, it's technically possible and easy to do. I'm not so sure if it violates any agreements that you make during the purchase from Blizzard.

Anyways: Diablo III includes a "global play" function, which simply lets you select the desired server to play on in the options. This means if you plan on purchasing the game using a VPN or something, you can simply create a US account and then still play with that account from Europe, or you can send the game as a gift to someone via email.

Notice, however, that if you create a US account, your home region will be "US", which means that when the addon for Diablo III gets released, you will only be able to play it on the US release, which is usually 8 hours after EU release :)

Comment: Who cares about all this legalese anyway ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Lawyers, so they can better sue ppl.

Answer (score 1):

Diablo is not region specific so however you chose to get your key it does not matter. However, characters on European servers are stuck there and vice versa. But, you cannot send a key to another account.

Answer (score 1):

At present, you cannot transfer copies of Diablo III from one account to another, and it's not possible to buy Diablo III as a gift for another account, so your plan to create a US account and purchase Diablo III for your existing european account will not work.

Also, I'm not it all sure it's your account that determines your purchase price...I'm fairly certain you'd need to use a US proxy server in order to purchase Diablo III at the US rate, as Blizzard is likely filtering IP addresses to determine which region you are in, and connect you to the store for your region.

I'm not sure whether you'd have access to the European real-money store. Blizzard has made it clear that, while you have access to all regions' servers, you have access to the real money store in only one region. That could be based on the region that you purchased the game in, or the region that your current IP address maps to, in the latter case, you'd be gold if you could just use a US proxy once to buy the game, in the former, you'd only have access to the gold auction house on your local servers.