# Can I play Diablo 3 on US servers with a Euro Key?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buying Diablo 3 in a different region](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/buying-diablo-3-in-a-different-region)

I was just asking if I can play Diablo 3 on the US servers if I have a Euro Key? Can I play with my mates or can you only play on the EU side?

Comment: Hey Jake! Someone seem's to have asked basically the exact same question before you :)  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/buying-diablo-3-in-a-different-region

Answer (score 3):

With [*Global Play*](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5203654/Introducing_Global_Play_for_Diablo%C2%AE_III-5_1_2012) you can play in any region. However, characters, stash, etc. are **not** shared between regions.