# Are guest passes region locked to the same region as the game you purchased?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I buy a US version of D3, can a friend use EU Battle.net with my guest pass?

I know that guest passes [don't have Global Play](http://us.battle.net/support/en/article/diablo-iii-starter-edition-guest-pass), but that's not exactly what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can use it. I have a friend in China that is currently using my guest pass from a U.S. retail copy of the game.