# Activate US retail copy of Diablo 3 on EU account

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Buying Diablo 3 in a different region](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64356/buying-diablo-3-in-a-different-region)

Just like the title says. If I buy a physical retail copy of Diablo 3 from a store in the US can I activate the key on my EU battle.net account?

Comment: Duplicate it is. I will post my experience as soon as I get my hands on a copy.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm for anyone reading this: it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have friends who have purchased the EU copies and have been able to log into the US servers in order to play with our small group of gamers. The catch was they had to start their accounts from scratch, don't know if they went back to EU if it would still be there or not. However I don't see why we couldn't do the same, there is a selection for it in the options menu although I haven't personally tried it on a US copy myself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can switch between different regions using the menu in the options. You're characters aren't shared between regions, but they should be stored just fine if you want to play in more than one region.